# iOS Centring UITableViewCell label with disclosure indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints

I am looking for a way to enter a label within a table cell that also has a disclosure indicator. The problem i'm having at the moment is that it seems like the disclosure indicator is being ignored when calculating the label's positions

Heres a picture:

[image: picture]

So as you can see the label is centred in the area between the left side of the cell and the left side of the indicator, if it was centred in the cell it would sit below the nav bar heading.

Any help is appreciated thankyou

From within the storyboard

[image]

Comment: can't you just extend the labels width to the width of the cell?

Comment: But thats the thing,  the cells width seems to not include the indicator

Comment: could you show a screenshot from your storyboard rather than from the simulator? :)

Comment: also, are you using a custom or a default `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Custom cell @nburk and have added a pic

Comment: all right, I am preparing an answer :)

Comment: I added the answer, note that your problem should go away if you removed the disclosure indicator, right? this is because the label always gets centered within the `contentView` whose size depends on that fact whether a disclosure indicator is present or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, first an explanation for your issue. It has to do with the *anatomy* of a `UITableViewCell`. With *anatomy*, I mean the fact that the `UITableViewCell` for you is just a *container* for another *container*, which is the `contentView` (you can also see this one in your storyboard).

When you are operating in *Storyboards*, you are solely operating on the `contentView`, not on the actual `UITableViewCell`. So, when you setup your `UILabel` to be *centered on the X-axis* with *AutoLayout*, *AutoLayout* will always try to center it within the `contentView`, not in the outer container (i.e. the `UITableViewCell`). Then, when you add a *disclosure indicator* to the `UITableViewCell`, the `contentView` automatically gets shrinked in its width because the cell makes space for the disclosure indicator and wants to prevent you from adding UI elements in the right area that is reserved for the disclosure indicator.

Now, you have a few options around this:

1. you can edit the constraint directly and add a constant to it (which has to be the same value that the label gets shifted when you'd remove the indicator)

[image]

2. don't use the default disclosure indicator (i.e. don't tick the checkbox in Storyboards) and just add a `UIImageView` with an image that looks identical.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation, with option 1 will the disclosure indicator always take up 32 pixels?

Comment: On iOS 8 it's 34 pixels. Also Apple could change this value so this isn't a very sustainable solution.

Comment: agreed @DanielG! relying on that constant probably isn't the very best idea... one thing that _could_ be done is to calculate this value and then set the constant for the constraint in code (e.g. in `viewWillAppear`).

Comment: see my answer below, I'm calculating the difference between self.frame and self.contentView.frame

Answer (score 5):

To not be bound to any constants you can calculate the difference in widths of `frame` and `contentView.frame`. So first create an outlet collection like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *centerConstraintsToOffset;
```

Then add the center constraints that you want to be centered horizontally in cell to that outlet collection:

[image]

And finally add this code to your cell:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for constraint in centerConstraintsToOffset {
        constraint.constant = (frame.size.width - contentView.frame.size.width) / 2.0
    }
}
```

This also gives you flexibility of adding or removing cell accessories on the go, and your views will always be perfectly center aligned. Even if you remove the accessory at all.

Comment: Great solution to an annoying problem -- getting the width of the disclosure indicator at runtime.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Pavel's answer fixed the issue for me. After creating the IBOutlet collection as his answer demonstrates, here is his code example edited for **Swift 3**:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in self.centerConstraintsToOffset {
        constraint.constant = (frame.size.width - contentView.frame.size.width) / 2.0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed, adding a 'UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator' will shrink the space allotted for your cell's contentView. Another solution that doesn't require a custom indicator or guessing at an offset would be to programmatically add a UILabel to the root view of the cell, not the contentView. For example:

```
@property UILabel *label;

// ...

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.label removeFromSuperview];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.label.text = @"Motorsport";
    [self.label sizeToFit];
    label.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.size.height/2);
    [self addSubview:self.label];
}
```